# How do I add proxies to this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram

I am creating a login tool for Instagram, so far this works, but I want to make it so every time I login I have a different IP, how could I do this? This script always works on my local machine but when I run it on my server sometimes I get errors. I believe this is because it notices to many logins from the same IP.

code:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'
userAgent= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"

time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())

username = input("What is your username: ")
password = input("What is your password: ")

payload = {
'username': username,
'enc_password': f'#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:{password}',
'queryParams': {},
'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
}


with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers= {"user-agent":userAgent}
    s.headers.update({"Referer":link})
    r = s.get(link)
    csrf = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"",r.text)[0]
    r = s.post(login_url,data=payload,headers={
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
    "x-csrftoken":csrf
    })
    data = str(r.text)
    if 'authenticated":true' in data:
        print("login successful")
    else:
        print("login unsuccessful")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a session, you can add a proxy just like you have added headers, the code for that will look like:

```
s.proxies = {
  “http”: “http://10.10.10.10:8000”,
  “https”: “http://10.10.10.10:8000”,
}
```

In order to find proxy servers, you can use websites like [geonode](https://geonode.com/free-proxy-list).

And to change the proxies, you can make a list of proxies you would like to use from geonode, and then rotate them in `s.proxies`.

```
import random
proxy_list = [proxy1, proxy2, proxy3..]

pv = random.randint(0, len(proxy_list))

s.proxies = {
  "http": proxy_list[pv]
  "https": proxy_list[pv] 
}
```

Since you are trying to scrape a website, it is a common practice to check on robots.txt if that website allows the same or not.